# Adding a prefix to the String in Java?

Tags: java, string, concatenation

I know that adding a character in a string should take O(1) time. for eg:-

```
String S = "abc"
S = S+'z';
```

What if I want to do vice-versa, concatenating a String into char. Is it possible like this?

```
S = 'z'+S;
```

If yes, then how much time will it take? Does Java copies whole content of String S{O(n)} or just do adjust pointers in memory {O(1)}?

Thanks!

Comment: Look at the implementation of `StringBuilder`, which Java uses for String concatenation.

Comment: Are you *sure* that adding a character to a string should take O(1) time? Remember, strings are immutable...

Comment: Oops! Not sure actually!

Comment: Still if Java copies memory to make a new String, it will be quite fast, not like copying or adjusting chars in a String :-/

Comment: Copying memory is still an O(n) operation (in Java at least. I'm not sure what C/C++/other low-level languages can do with `memcpy` or something). It could be slower if you have to do lots of copying of lots of long strings.

Answer (score 2):

String is immutable. Thus there's no way this operation (of adding the prefix) to be O(1). It is at least linear with respect to the size of S. And... as it makes no sense (think about it) to be O(f(N)) where O(f(N)) > O(N), it means it's O(N). Pretty sure about this just from common sense.

Answer (score 0):

The order of concat does not matter. In recent versions of compilers this (usually) turns into byte code which uses a StringBuilder.

Comment: And how efficient is the `StringBuilder`?

Comment: I doesn't matter means that both the operation will have same complexity? Which is O(n) or O(1)?

Comment: You can almost think of it as an ArrayList only backed by a char[] rather than an Object[]. Depending on the types of operations you do it will be quite fast and efficient. If it is not sized properly to begin with, or you insert characters other than at the end, it is more expensive.